# This site have only a few hours and we have the 5 Vox Populi badge. It is normal?

Tags: discussion, badges

I see in the [Badge page](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi) that we have now 5 users with Vox Populi badge, but we have only a few hours online and only 40 questions. It is normal?

Comment: For private beta? Yes.

Comment: Note that Vox Populi counts votes on both questions and answers, and [we have more than twice as many answers as questions](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer).

Comment: 14 Vox Pupuli badges on the main site. 5 on meta.

Comment: Now there are nine on main.

Comment: @HDE226868 I guess that you meant "on meta".

Comment: @VictorStafusa No, I meant what I said. See the list.

Comment: @HDE226868 Odd. It presented more people for me earlier. It also shows only 1 for meta. Maybe a caching bug?

Comment: @VictorStafusa I would guess so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It is normal?

## No!

This happens because there is a strong pressure to contribute early in the private beta:

- If there is few activity during the private beta, SE will merciless close the site. They already did that some times before, so the danger is real.
- People here are legitimately eager to contribute in building a working community as soon as possible. The result is many people eager to post questions and answers.
- The community still have no moderators, established policies or well-defined players, and many people interested in defining that, so they need to work to take a head up before things settle down and things turn to be harder to change then.

After a couple of days, specially in late private beta and the first months of public beta, that level of contribution is unlikely to happen again. I think that after the things here cool down, we will only see such high level of participation in late public beta and after graduation.

Basically what is happening is similar to when a new restaurant opens in the city with a grand opening party: A lot of people come and the restaurant is crowded in its very first day. After a couple of days, the number of people frequenting there drops significantly before stabilizing.

Comment: Few activity? [Gamification](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61762/gamification)...

Comment: @Zizouz212 [Relationships and Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating)

Comment: We'll be going on and on... [Gamification](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification) again...

Answer (score 2):

I quote from my message in the site chat room:

> who are we?
>   USERS!
>   are we targeting badges?
>   GET ALL THE BADGES!

[<sup>(source)</sup>](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25118?m=22341720#22341720)